# Jqgrid. How to handle server response before in will be passed to grid

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have a common structure of JSON data that come back from server, it contains some additional info about errors etc. How can I handle this data(check error info) and then pass only required data to grid.

This is JSON data structure:

```
{
  "errorinfo": "foo", 
  "errormsg": "foo", 
  "errorCode": "foo"
  "**jqgridData**": [
    { 
      "total": "xxx", 
      "page": "yyy", 
      "records": "zzz",
      "rows" : [
        {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
        {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
          ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I wand to process this JSON data and pass to grid only "**jqgridData**"

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the JSON data has one small error. The string

```
{ "errorinfo": "foo", "errormsg": "foo", "errorCode": "foo" "jqgridData": [ {
```

must be changed to

```
{ "errorinfo": "foo", "errormsg": "foo", "errorCode": "foo", "jqgridData": [ {
```

(comma between `"errorCode": "foo"` and `"jqgridData"` must be inserted). I hope the problem come during posting of the data in the question text only.

To your main question. The [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) allows you to read you practically any data. You data should be read with the following [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data):

```
jsonReader: {
    root: "jqgridData.0.rows",
    page: "jqgridData.0.page",
    total: "jqgridData.0.total",
    records: "jqgridData.0.records"
}
```

(where '0' element is needed as the index because of `jqgridData` is additionally an array).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that we can use different levels of array in jsonReader. It is very useful!